# Cant add users to InfluxDb 2.0 GUI/Docker

Tags: docker, grafana, influxdb

Im using unraid server and the Docker image InfluxDB.
I'm able to go to mine localhost:8086, and I create root user (admin user), but then, I do not have the option for adding more users.
I can add more organizations and buckets, but I simply can't add any users?
Any hints? Im new to this InfluxDB, my ultimate goal is to hook up with Grafana and Telegraf..

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that you can add users using the [command from the docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/users/create-user/#create-a-user-with-a-password-and-organization).

With docker this should be possible with something like this (given your container name os influxdb2):

```
$ docker exec influxdb2 influx user create \
  -n <username> \
  -p <password> \
  -o <org-name>
```

Comment: This gives me Error: failed to lookup org with name "myOrg": 401 Unauthorized: unauthorized access

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into the Docker image itself and using the influx command directly to see if you can create a new user - it may give you some insight into what's going on.

```
docker exec -it imagename bash
```

then when you have a shell

```
influx user create -n username
```

As said the command

```
docker exec IMAGE influx user create -n username
```

should achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just see this question. For me this way worked:

```
docker ps
```

It will list the container_ids with its name. Get the container_id of influxdb. Then:

```
docker exec -it <container_Id> bash

influx user create -n <name_of_user> -o <name_of_org> -p <password> -t "<token>"
```

Note you should use exactly the name of organization that you have and the right token. You can choose name of user and password whatever you want.